# jquery nested sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-lists

i have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test-list").sortable({
        items: "> li",
        handle : '.handle',
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.6,
        update : function () {
            var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
            $("#info").load("process-sortable.asp?"+order+"&id=catid&order=orderid&table=tblCats");
        }
    });
    $("#test-sub").sortable({
        containment: "ul",
        items: "li",
        handle : '.handle',
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.6,
        update : function () {
            var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
            $("#info").load("process-sortable.asp?"+order+"&id=catid&order=orderid&table=tblCats");
        }
    });
});
```

for this kind of UL

```
<ul id="test-list">
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul id="test-sub">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

but it can be changed dynamiclly...
when i drag and drop the main li it is working
when i do it with the childs it will drag the main one

what is wrong?

Comment: When I use items:"li" I can drag and drop from parents into children but not the other way around. Not sure how this "items" option works..

Comment: my fiddle on how to make sortable, N-level-deep (configurable) embedded lists using jquery-ui: https://jsfiddle.net/nickleus/j7bm8jrq/15/

Comment: @NickHumphrey this beast of a fiddle you created is nearly perfect for what I am looking to do. The one change I could use help with is limiting the movement. I forked your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/SavageCatHV/u0hr6mLa/  The change I'm trying to accomplish is a week can be moved but it must stay as a week or at it current indention. Likewise, the day can move to any week but also must stay at it's current indentation.  I have an SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016071/jquery-ui-sorting-some-elements-of-nested-list. I do hope you'll review it. Hope not harder than I think

Answer (score 1):

I blogged on this.  It's not that straight forward and a bit confusing, but simple really.

http://a.shinynew.me/post/4641524290/jquery-ui-nested-sortables

Comment: What do you mean by "no working that good"?  Can you explain in more detail what isn't working?

Comment: when you drag ul that have li under it they all get massy

Comment: Yes, it does get hectic.  The best way to stop the "flashing" is to increase the height of the nested ul.

Comment: @BurkeHolland It would be good if you have added the code snipped here. The link you provides is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a drag and drop script specially designed for nested structures
Check it out...
https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/