# How to drag a div that contains other divs that were dragged into it?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to solve for a problem, and haven't had much luck figuring it out on my own.

I have several container divs on my page.  The "ItemContainer" holds "items" that are draggable.  The "MainHome" holds a secondary "ItemContainer" (where the "items" are to be dragged to) as well as some other divs.  The "MainHome" is also draggable into a "Playarea".  What I need to have happen, is when "items" are dragged into the "ItemContainer" contained within the "MainHome" they need to be attached to it so that if "MainHome" is then dragged, those items drag with it.

They will need to remain individually draggable as well.

Here is my generic code:

```
<div id="leftrail">
    <div id="manager">
        <div id="somediv">
            <h2>Text</h2>
            <div id="bubble">Text Here</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="ItemContainer">
                <div id="Item1">Item 1</div>
                <div id="Item2">Item 2</div>
                <div id="Item3">Item 3</div>
                <div id="Item4">Item 4</div>
                <div id="Item5">Item 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
    <div>
        <div id="MyContainer">
            <div id="SecondaryItemContainer">Drag Items Here</div>
            <div>Some text</div>
            <div>Some more text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="MainContent">    
    <div>Some stuff here</div>    
    <div>Some stuff here</div>      
    <div>Some stuff here</div>    
    <div id="BigContainer">Drag the MyContainer Here</div>      
</div>
```

The full demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6pVG/1/

Comment: What have your tried so far ? In general you should reposition them inside the DOM.. putting the elements inside their new container (*in terms of DOM and not just css positioning*) will result in what you want..

Comment: Help us help you! Create a jsfiddle!

Comment: Gaby - I'm not sure what you mean by positioning inside the DOM (most of my work is server-side, so not terribly familiar with client-side scripting).  Do you mean using append/prepend?

Comment: Aktee - I added the jsfiddle demo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here's a nested sortable solution: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

   And here's an improvement on how the serialization is handled in the above solution: http://markmintoff.com/2011/05/jqueryui-hierarchical-sorting/
2. Another solution: http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/
3. And, here are the SO duplicates of this question:

   - [jQuery Nested Sortable - Move LI elements within all available UL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188153/jquery-nested-sortable-move-li-elements-within-all-available-uls)
   - [jquery nested sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487026/jquery-nested-sortable-list)
   - [jQuery Sortable - Nested UL elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290494/jquery-sortable-nested-ul-elements)

Comment: Thank you for all the great resources.  Had I thought of the word "nested" I'm sure I would have found these, but my brain was so fried that figuring out what to call this was lacking!  ;o)

Comment: No worries. I know that feeling all too well. Glad I could help.

Comment: Well, on second thought, these aren't quite what I'm looking for.  I need to move items from one holder to a different holder.  I'm not using UL lists for this.  Will have to keep looking...

Comment: I think this can be accomplished with the options available in JQuery UI. I recommend playing with sortable interaction (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Comment: Can you look at the jsfiddle link I have now posted in my original question?

Comment: I'll check out your code. This question/answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085952/jquery-nested-sortable-draggable-not-working-help-please

Comment: That last one is PERFECT!  Works...and...easy dumb. Like I feel like an idiot now (in a good way).  Thanks so much JSuar!  You're a life saver!